# Input string was not in a correct format while updating row in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am having problem when update my OrderStatus 'P' TO 'A'. Datatype in
 SQL server is `varchar(50)`.

```
 protected void grdNewOrder_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE tblPurchase SET OrderStatus ='A' WHERE PurchaseID= @id";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(grdNewOrder.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            LoadNewOrders();

            lblsucessmsg.Text = "Selected Record Updated";
            lblerror.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblsucessmsg.Text = "";
        lblerror.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: And what was that error?

Comment: Assign this section `grdNewOrder.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()` to a variable before converting it to an Int and check if it is a number. You cannot use `Convert.ToInt32` on a non-numeric string

Comment: @Dumisani thanks, I have been trying to solve this problem for last three hours but thank you very much for saving my time by solving my problem.

Comment: @Arslanjappa glad I could help